# Blender using too much memory?

Tags: memory-management

I have a project with 4 objects in the scene. The total face count is 46,594. The viewport shading is set to Solid mode. Yet, my memory usage is at 15 GB. I've applied the multires modifier on 2 objects with the viewport level at 0. At 1, the memory usage goes up to 32 GB.

What am I doing wrong ?

My specs:
I7 3930k
32GB RAM
Gtx 980ti

File Link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XmkH0xof6VzGU1cBndevUEKt3V8VWCoS/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Also I'm noticing that in edit mode, as I select faces of an object, the memory usage increases exponentially. Almost 1 GB per tiny face selected. Is this normal ?

Comment: Hey! Could you pack your Blend.file and upload it to https://blend-exchange.com/ please :)

Comment: The file is almost 1.2 GB. Can I upload such a big file ?

Comment: 1.2GB is quiete large,  what exactly causes this large of a file if you only have 4 Objects with just 46k faces? You can try to make a copy file and strip everything that does not impact the lagging and upload it

Comment: Is it because I'm using 2-4 materials/textures on each object? Would you accept a Google drive link instead?

Comment: The memory usage is most likely due to using high res textures, try to use lower resolution while working on your file.

Comment: You can upload it to dropbox, googledrive or Wetransfer and ill try my best

Comment: Here's the file: https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/vHmGjk3ipgOdvL4NFHoq_evvaRSyFclPlSq-4vUNYZG-xyZ8ENVoSEBWMQbkiab0tJLDaZrFUl4kO9yA4RNTvjb1R3J6GmvUdnEcf6MMyeoXNeCokUMfzbSobtXRIXQ=s0-d-e1-ft#https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_generic_x64.png

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: I can't download it sadly

Comment: Sorry for that. Once more :.    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XmkH0xof6VzGU1cBndevUEKt3V8VWCoS/view?usp=share_link

Comment: How do you get a file to 1.2GB with 46k faces? Massive simulations? If it's only the Multires in Render Mode, delete it b4 upload. Also check if that reduces the RAM in VP.

Comment: I have no clue Frederik :) I've already uploaded the file ... Please check it out if you're free.

Comment: The google drive link is private. You need to change the access permissions to "link/public" (or so) so everyone that has the link can access the file.

Comment: Sorry again ! The link has been updated ...    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XmkH0xof6VzGU1cBndevUEKt3V8VWCoS/view?usp=share_link

Comment: The file is really huge for the little meshes you have in there. I've extracted the textures. That's about 185 MB. So the remaining blend file is still 1 GB big. It looks like the two *MultiRes* modifiers eat 850 MB for breakfast. If the modifiers are applied (or removed) then the file size drops to 150 MB with 1.1 million vertices. I've expected something around 60-90 MB. Well, ok. But 850 MB doesn't look right, it looks like a memory leak or bug. Tested with Blender 3.4.0b. Maybe you can drop the file size if you apply new MultRes modifiers + "ShrinkWrap-copy" the original mesh.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll give it a try ... But can you confirm that it's a bug ?